# mipmap-anydpi-v26 vs roundIcon

Tags: android, xml, android-8.0-oreo

Adaptive launcher icons [introduced in Android Oreo](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive.html) are defined using different mipmap folders with PNGs but also adding a folder `mipmap-anydpi-v26` which contains an XML representation (which in turn references a color and a foreground PNG).

In the `AndroidManifest.xml` there is an `icon` and `roundIcon` attribute for the `application` element.  Should you specify an XML for each type? e.g. `ic_launcher.xml` and `ic_launcher_round.xml`? If so, is their content identical (since the foreground image that the xml refers to is the same regardless of shape)?

Comment: I can tell you that the Android Studio 3.0 Image Asset wizard sets up XML for both types, with identical content. Android 7.1 was where `roundIcon` was introduced, and so it will not use `mipmap-anydpi-v26` resources (7.1 was API Level 25) anyway.

Comment: Good background. A fair assumption would be that both are "needed" if the tool generates them. Probably to simplify the business logic in the Android native layer when scaling. But it is completely redundant. It would be interesting to know for sure...